# Apply Css to the Last Parent Div

Tags: html, css

I want to apply Css on class **fancybox-inner** which is the last parent of class **main-content**. I dont want to directly define the class and apply properties. Because I have multiple classes with the same name i.e **fancybox-inner**. So I want to target **fancybox-inner** on behalf of **main-content**.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fancybox">

 <div class="fancybox-inner">

    <div class="main-content">

      <!--- Some Content ------>

    </div>

 </div>

<div>
```

**What I have tried so far :**

```
  .main-content < .fancybox-inner {
      width:1000px !important;
  }
```

Comment: You have to choose jQuery/JavaScript to achieve this

Answer (score 4):

Use : nth-last-child() Selector

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-last-child

**updated Answer**

```
.main-content:parent {//specify properties for fancybox-inner here}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how will this work with my code ?

Comment: **I want to apply Css on class fancybox-inner which is the last parent of class main-content.** are you right saying this ?

Comment: the css should be applied to fancybox-inner. Simple is that. But using class main-content

Comment: all i mean in last comment is you can't say `main-content` being parent of `fancybox-inner`.

Comment: main-content is the first child of fancybox-inner. We must use these two classes to apply css on fancybox-inner

Comment: .main-content:parent {//specify properties}

Answer (score 1):

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Sorry to say but there is no way to do this the way you asked.

A possible solution is the go the other way.

```
.fancybox .fancybox-inner {
    // CODE HERE
}
```

This will target the fancybox class, then target the fancybox-inner (Which will ONLY target the one that is inside the fancybox class)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note though, if you have multiple .fancybox-inner in .fancybox, it'll target all of them.

Comment: to last comment of Hamedar, you could use '.fancybox > .fancybox-inner' to be more specific. As it will only target the div with class name '.fancybox-inner' which is directly inside or at first place in a div with class name '.fancybox'. Still it will target to all similar divs in relation but not beyond of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one extra class to that element

```
<div id="mywrapper">
<div class="fancybox">

 <div class="fancybox-inner extra-class">

    <div class="main-content">

      <!--- Some Content ------>

    </div>

 </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Then your css will be :

```
 #mywrapper > fancybox >fancybox-inner {
      width:1000px !important;
  }
```

Comment: I cannot add class to that div. Cz its being generted from fancybox

Comment: What about doing .fancybox > .fancybox-inner {}

Comment: Nope cant do this either. I have too many classes with same names

Comment: Can you cover main fancybox with a div with id="my-cover", after that do #my-cover > .fancybox > .fancybox-inner {}

Comment: I cant made changes on those upper divs, they are generting from Fancybox

Comment: Did edit in my answer, what about doing so, just wrap whole of the Fancybox in your own div

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use jquery to access parent node and apply css to that. Possibly like,

`$(".main-content").parent().css({'width':'1000px !important'});`

Answer (score 0):

You could use wrapCSS property to set your custom class

```
$(".selector").fancybox({
    wrapCSS : 'my-custom-css-class'
});
```